# Enum warning : outside the range

Tags: c++, enums, warnings

I have the following code. There are two enums. One with 16 values (A_) and
the other with 15 values (A1_).

```
#include <iostream>

typedef enum
{   
    A_0 = 0,
    A_1,
    A_2,
    A_3,
    A_4,
    A_5,
    A_6,
    A_7,
    A_8,
    A_9,
    A_10,
    A_11,
    A_12,
    A_13,
    A_14,
    A_15,
    A_FIRST = A_0,
    A_LAST = A_15
} a_t;

typedef enum
{   
    A1_0 = 0,
    A1_1,
    A1_2,
    A1_3,
    A1_4,
    A1_5,
    A1_6,
    A1_7,
    A1_8,
    A1_9,
    A1_10,
    A1_11,
    A1_12,
    A1_13,
    A1_14,
    A1_FIRST = A1_0,
    A1_LAST = A1_14
} a1_t;

int 
main()
{   
    a_t m = static_cast<a_t> (static_cast<int> (A_LAST) + 1); // WARNING
    std::cout << m;
    a1_t m1 = static_cast<a1_t> (static_cast<int> (A1_LAST) + 1); // NO WARNING
    std::cout << m1;
    return 0;
}
```

g++ compilation:

> g++ -Wconversion enum_testing.cpp

I get a warning message:

```
enum_testing.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
enum_testing.cpp:49:64: warning: the result of the conversion is     unspecified because ‘16’ is outside the range of type ‘a_t’ [-Wconversion]
     a_t m = static_cast<a_t> (static_cast<int> (A_LAST) + 1);
```

Question: Why I get a warning message for first declaration with enum A_ and not a message with enum A1_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the compiler is free to chose whatever underlying type is big enough for an enum declaration to hold all its data.

In your case it apparently chose an integral type to represent `a_t` that has an (possibly imaginary) bitsize of 4.

This type can only hold values from 0 to 15. You try `static_cast<a_t> (16)`, which is outside of the representable values, thus the undefined behaviour. This is not true for `a1_t` - you got "lucky" - because here it would be `static_cast<a1_t> (15)` and 15 is representable by the underlying type of `a1_t`.

Comment: Note, this is not undefined behavior until C++17.

Answer (score 1):

The range of an [enum](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum) is:

> [...]If the underlying type is not fixed, the range is all values
>   possible for the smallest bit field large enough to hold all
>   enumerators of the target enumeration[...]

So `15` fits within this range while `16` does not. This is unspecified behavior prior to C++17 and will be undefined behavior after. The change was due to [DR 1766: Values outside the range of the values of an enumeration](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1766)  which says:

> Although issue 1094 clarified that the value of an expression of enumeration type might not be within the range of the values of the enumeration after a conversion to the enumeration type (see 5.2.9 [expr.static.cast] paragraph 10), the result is simply an unspecified value. This should probably be strengthened to produce undefined behavior, in light of the fact that undefined behavior makes an expression non-constant. See also 9.6 [class.bit] paragraph 4.

and the resolution was to make it undefined behavior.